# Should I wait before publishing App with Core-Data and iCloud until it is more stable?

Tags: core-data, icloud

(as at 1st June 2012)

A very simple question I would really appreciate input from others (I think we all could) who are either wondering the same or have decided to go with it (if so, any user experiences shared would be great).

I have 2 main issues which seem common on stackoverflow and on various blogs, so I know I'm not the only person experiencing them.

1. Occasionally my sync gets corrupted for one reason or another and the sync either fails on certain data or fails to sync altogether.
2. Pre populating data is essential for my app, there's no reliable way of doing this (without asking the user - which isn't reliable)

I've seen many good work arounds to both these issues but I can't help feeling that my users will encounter problems still.

I'd be really interested to learn of any experiences particularly from those that have decided to publish using iCloud and Core-Data.

iCloud has been around a while now but even on iOS 5.1.1 it doesn't seem stable enough, surely a more reliable version can't be too far away.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer this one without "*Making statements based on opinion*", but it's one worth giving partially backed up opinions on to hopefully save others some time and frustration.

My opinion is that it's just **not ready**. I unfortunately have an app in the wild at the moment based around CoreData + iCloud and even though we danced around a number of iCloud bugs to finally get it stable enough to pass reasonably thorough testing some users are still running into the corrupted sync states. I've spent a healthy portion of my recent life trying to make it work and am currently reluctantly reimplementing the app without Core Data. I really hope that it stabilizes soon as I genuinely like most of it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i have decided not to go with iCloud for now, cant wait for CoreData & iCloud to work better together.